# Ok in simulator but throwing exception in ios device

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad, ios-simulator

when i am running my app in the simulator everything is working perfectly .But when i running the same app in the Ipad exception is being thrown.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil**.
    In my app at one step i have to request a web-URl and need to parsed the returned `JSON` response. But I have checked the web-url and have been able to parse perfectly in simulator. But all the problem has been arisen in real ios device.But I think i have identified the code where it is getting wrong.

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getParsedJSON:(NSString*) urlString {
NSLog(@"################################################################################");
NSLog(@"getParsedJSON => urlString:");
NSLog(@"%@", urlString);

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *response1 = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData* response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response1 error:&error];

//NSData* response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"getParsedJSON => responseString:\n%@", responseString);
NSLog(@"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
NSError* jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary* parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError]; // here is place where exception seems to be thrown.
if (jsonParsingError) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR in parsing JSON: %@", jsonParsingError);
} else {
    NSLog(@"getParsedJSON => parsedJSON: \n%@", [parsedJSON description]);
}
NSLog(@"################################################################################");    
return parsedJSON;
```

}

I have  identified the line where it seems to be wrong .I have also attached screen shot of the exception report.[image: screenshot of the console].Hoping for your experienced reply.

Comment: You can check whether the error is nil after sending the request. If it is not, print the error userInfo to know what is happening.

Comment: You should also check that `sendSynchronousRequest` is not nil.

Comment: @serrrgi I have already checked if the error is nil.But like i said all the problem seems to be in decvice

Comment: The device is connected to the interwebs?

Comment: yes. the device is connected... because if there was any problem the internet the app should throw exception in the simulator...

Comment: @Wain yea it seems that `sendSynchronousRequest` is nil.But I am confused. what should i do now??? because the url work perfectly in simulator

Comment: At least log the request, response, response1 and error variables.

Comment: As Ankit indicates, your NSLog shows that the response string was nil, before you even attempted to decode the JSON.  This isn't a JSON issue.  What we have here is a failure to communicate.

Comment: Hint:  You should ALWAYS check `error` parms, ESPECIALLY those from comm operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS we can see from the logs your response string is null while you are using it on your Device. This may be due to some internet access problem. Try to Use:

```
if([response isequaltostring:@"(null)"]||response == nil || response.length == 0)
{
NSError* jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary* parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError]; // here is place where exception seems to be thrown.
if (jsonParsingError) {
NSLog(@"ERROR in parsing JSON: %@", jsonParsingError);
} 
else {
NSLog(@"getParsedJSON => parsedJSON: \n%@", [parsedJSON description]);
     }
}
```

Also try to add the exceptional breakpoint and post where exactly the app crashed.
Let me know the result.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set an exception breakpoint in Xcode - there are many posts here on how to do that. Second, after each of you statements where an object is created or returned, add an assert:

```
NSURL *foo = ...
assert(foo);
```

Doing this will help you find the first issue not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

As per your logs, your response string is empty!

Do the below two things!

- Add NSLog(@"Response Data: %@",response); and check if the response has value?
- If 'response' has value, convert it to a string - Log the string value - And check if the any of the key has nil value?

'NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData' method would crash if it finds any key with nil value.